# Can not add new fonts to xcode framework

Tags: xcode, fonts, frameworks

I have issues adding fonts to the framework i am making. The nee fonts show up in interface builder but not when I would like to instantiate uifont programatically. Even if they show at interface builder, they dont show on device. I have checked all the steps, the target, build phases copying the bundle resources and the info list font supported by application.

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you got to fix it?

Comment: No i ended up adding the font to the main project.